# Mongoose Sharing Validation/Pre-Save Methods Across NodeJS Apps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If one Nodejs app connects to a Mongo instance, and that app has defined a `User` schema with `pre-save` hooks, validation, etc.

And then another Nodejs app connects to the same database, and tries to register a `User` schema with different properties.

And then the second app saves a `User`

What happens?

I'm confused with how two Nodejs apps may communicate to the same database.

For example, it's very easy to see how one might want to have V2 of an `api` on a separate nodejs app developed by a separate team.  But they will plug it into the same database and use the same Schema (or will they?), and I'm confused with how things are shared between the two apps.

Any help clarifying this in best-practices would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer in the Documentation.

> This connection object is then used to create and retrieve models. Models are always scoped to a single connection. [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

And

> Models are fancy constructors compiled from our Schema definitions. [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Which explains that a DB Connection 1's Schema Definitions (pre-save, etc), do not affect DB Connection 2's writes/etc.

Essentially, they are completely independent of validation and everything else.  They only need to be OK in their own context.